# Is there a way to print something in console that doesn't scroll down? (In C)

Tags: c, printf

Well, maybe if I offer a little context this will be more understandable.

I want to print "Inventory" in the first line of my main, but I don't want "Inventory" to move from its place, so, while the rest of my commands show in console, and will scroll down, this particular line "Inventory will stay in its place." 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVItr.png

I'm not sure if this can be done in C

Comment: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html You can always manually specify the properties of lines in ncurses. In particular, you can reserve a line for "Inventory" and define scrolling actions for the rest of the terminal screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite hard in plain C due to how the console works.

There is, however a library that has done everything for you: NCurses: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

Comment: Were it "impossible", the NCurses library - written in "plain C" - couldn't do it.

Comment: NCurses uses specific functionality of the terminal it is connected to, so it makes some assumptions about what the terminal does and does not support. Plain C (as in printf etc) assumes the it can only pass UTF characters to its stdout and the terminal will interpet it. So by using NCurses you are stepping away from basic stdout and start to interact with the terminal on a level that not every terminal is able to deal with. So I want to argue that, since plain old C only spews in a direction and prays for a decent terminal to be there, you are stepping away from plain old C.

Comment: Your argument is based on constructing an artificial constraint of limiting "plain C" to "printf()".  And even that's not good enough.  You **can** use `printf()` to do things like send terminal control sequences (http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) to do **exactly** what NCurses does - in "plain C".  See for yourself:  ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses/current/

Comment: NCurses makes the code compatible, in case the OP want to port it to another OS. Also, it relieves OP of the burden to find out what exact type of terminal is used and what commands it supports.