# C : apply formatting (right align, center, etc.) to terminal text output

Tags: c, terminal, formatting, format

I would like to make my terminal text output nicer in my C program. I would like to know where I can find info on:

- Display text X characters from the left border
- Display text X characters from the right border
- Display centered text
- How to make text float at top of terminal (e.g. table header) such that columns are easier to read (the header will show what each column means and, as there are a lot of rows output, a header floating at top would be nice)

I don't have time to make a GUI. Are the above possible in C? I know things like displaying text X characters from left border are possible in C++ with `std::setw`, but how do I implement such functionality in C?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to print something in console that doesn't scroll down? (In C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143260/is-there-a-way-to-print-something-in-console-that-doesnt-scroll-down-in-c)

Comment: ncurses  could help you

Comment: I came across ncurses and would like to learn it, but I don't have time right now to learn a new UI language and want more of an implementation like std::setw. ncurses is overkill in my case.

Comment: If you think about it, using `ncurses` *is* the time saver here. It is not a language but a set of C functions, and writing similar functionality manually would take you *much* longer. Plus, it's a cross-platform library for *many* platforms.

Comment: std::setw doesn't know about the terminal's actual width, so centering is only within arbitrary bounds.

Comment: If you want to succeed with something new you'll have to learn

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution for the first three tasks:

- calculate the width of your printed line
- prepend spaces to make this line indented, centered or right aligned

Assume a screen-width of 80 charcters for "right aligned" and "centered"

The more complete solution is the ncurses library